# How does the compiler select the architecture for asm_*.S files?

Tags: go, cross-platform

I wanted to know how the Go compiler selects the architecture for assembler files such as in '[sync/atomic](https://golang.org/src/sync/atomic/)'. Is there a compiler flag?

Comment: From the GOARCH environment variable, which defaults to the architecture of the machine you're executing the build on. See the documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Go compiler targets the architecture you are running. You can set the `GOARCH` environment variable to override this. See: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

Comment: Wow, that's my comment, almost verbatim.